# In the class context how to create a new object by new self and new parent?

Tags: php, class, object

I'm using **PHP 7.1.11**

In the PHP manual I come across the following sentence :

> In the class context, it is possible to create a new object by *new
>   self* and *new parent*.

I didn't understand what this sentence actually mean? Also, there is not a single working demonstrative example has been given in the manual. So, I'm not at all able to understand the meaning of this sentence.

If someone could explain the meaning along-with the appropriate, suitable, working, demonstrative code-example each for ***new self*** and ***new parent*** it would be of great help to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means that you can use the keyword `self` as a shortcut to refer to the class you're in, and the keyword `parent` to refer to the class you extended.

```
class Foo
{

    public static function thing()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function method()
    {
        $foo = new self(); // Creates an instance of Foo
        self::thing();     // Statically calls method thing in class Foo
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function method()
    {
        $bar = new self();   // Creates an instance of Bar
        $bar = new self;     // Same thing, without optional parens
        $foo = new parent(); // Creates an instance of Foo
        parent::thing();     // Statically calls method thing in class Foo
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm no where seeing the method thing(). Where it is declared and defined? Without even defining the method thing() how you can say that it's static and it should get called statically? Can the non-static methods be called using objects created with new self and new parent? If yes how? If no why? Please update your answer to answer these questions. Thank You.

Comment: Updated for clarity.

Comment: Can the non-static methods be called using objects created with new self and new parent? If yes how? If no why? Please update your answer to answer these questions, so that it would be the complete justice to the question. Thank You.

Comment: _"Can the non-static methods be called using objects created with new self and new parent?"_ Yes, just like you normally would: `$foo = new parent(); $foo->whatever();`

Comment: Instead of creating an object by using self or parent can the static method be called in this fashion; in parent class 'Foo' as Foo::thing(); in subclass Bar as Bar::thing();?